# Turning a NB into a Repeatable Script?

Tags: polynomials, scripting

I am interested in "automating" the following notebook file so that I can execute it many times to generate many plots.

```
roots = x /. NSolve[Sum[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]*x^k, {k, 0, 1000}] ==
 0, x, Reals]
difs = Differences[roots]
a = Tally[difs]
ListPlot[a, AxesLabel -> {diffs, occurences}, PlotLabel -> "A Degree 1000" , PlotRange -> Full]
Export["plot.pdf", %]
```

Each time the code is evaluated, I of course obtain a different plot. I would like to have maybe 100 of the plots but this would be rather tedious as I have to save the plot output as a PDF individually and run the whole notebook each time. I also want to do other degrees than 1000 so I will definitely need to automate this process. I have looked into the Wolfram Script stuff, but am a bit lost/ not sure what to do. Is it possible to turn this notebook file (with 4 cells of evaluation) into a script such that I can just run it over and over with one easy command in a command line to generate multiple plots?

Any help with this issue is immensely appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Add another line to export plot as PDF and wrap the whole process in a `Do` loop?

Comment: @Pinti this just results in tons of errors though

Comment: I do not think you need to use Wolfram Script. You can just use `Table` to `Map`. Also, please post code, not images with code.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Sorry about that , I put the code now. What do you mean by use Table to Map? Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generates and exports 10 images with your code:

```
Table[
 roots = 
  x /. NSolve[
    Sum[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]*x^k, {k, 0, 1000}] == 0, 
    x, Reals];
 difs = Differences[roots];
 a = Tally[difs]; 
 Export["/some/path/plot" <> ToString[i] <> ".pdf", 
  ListPlot[a, AxesLabel -> {diffs, occurences}, 
   PlotLabel -> "A Degree 1000", PlotRange -> Full]]
 , {i, 10}]
```